# (Server Error in '/' Application. Could not find file )error in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, azure, cloud-hosting

I have converted my asp.net web project to Cloud Service. When i compile it on my local machine, it works fine. But when i deploy it on Windows Azure, and run it as *.cloudapp.net , it shows following error. It doesn't upload or download any file. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**Error :**`Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find file 'E:\approot\uploads\129517348374782571'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'E:\approot\uploads\129517348374782571'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'E:\approot\uploads\129517348374782571'.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +12892807
   System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length() +12550108
   EsraSon2.CourseList.gvPaths_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\canosum\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EsraSon2\EsraSon2\CourseList.aspx.cs:78
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +1203
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3691
`

**upload code :**

```
 string temp = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime().ToString();
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploads") +"\\"+ temp);
                BLLFileUpload m_helper = new BLLFileUpload();
                DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                m_helper.InsertUploadFiletoDB(temp, FileUpload1.FileName, date, 1, Convert.ToInt32(gvSemesters.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text));
```

**Download Code :**

```
BLLFileUpload m_helper = new BLLFileUpload();

            string tempname = m_helper.getFileRealName(gvPaths.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);  
            string fName = Server.MapPath("uploads")+ "\\" + tempname;
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fName);
            long sz = fi.Length;

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename = {0}", gvPaths.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text));
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", sz.ToString("F0"));
            Response.TransmitFile(fName);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many instances you are running, there is no guranttee that the file was upload to the same machine you are trying to download from since there are multiple servers.

All things that you need to persist, such as uploaded files should go to blob storage.

Here is a sample (for large files)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/687b2252-8b5e-473d-b522-ebb6b02693b7